# how do I toggle through filters in Tableau and generate an image for each

Tags: tableau-api

I have a graph in Tableau that has a filter on it. The filter is by company so I can toggle between the scores of different companies. and see the graph. Is there any way that I can make Tableau toggle through all of the filters and export an image for each?

Comment: can you show image

Comment: Add a screenshot to understand your problem.

Comment: You can if your workbook is on Tableau server. Using tabcmd and creating a batch file. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm